# How to avoid the creation of a complex aggregate root when I need just to show some information?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to integrate the DDD approach to my project and I faced a problem.

The problem is the creation of complex entities when I need just to display something. I use the aggregate roots when I need to create or update them, but I think it is overhead to do it just for displaying data.

I heard about the CQRS, but did not find any actual realization.
Tell me please what are you doing in that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use the aggregate roots when I need to create or update them, but I think it is overhead to do it just for displaying data.

Yup - a lot of people reached that same conclusion.

The usual answer is that if you are just reading/displaying/querying the data, that you don't go through the domain model at all -- just read only what you need from the persistent store, transform it into the representation the caller is expecting, and off it goes.

If the representation is expensive to make, then you might keep a hot cache of representations around (although now you also have to think about cache invalidation -- there are no magics, only trade offs).